# setonclicklistener not working twice inside running thread

Tags: android, multithreading, onclicklistener, wikitude

I am trying to close view by using cross image(cancel_video_image_view in the code) which is at the top right of the screen as seen in the image [demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhRj9.jpg). it is working for first time but fail to work for second time, why set on click listener not working for second time inside running thread?please help: 
[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhRj9.jpg)
**this is the code**

```
@Override 
public void onTargetRecognized(final Tracker tracker_, final String targetName_) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (targetName_.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("TargetOne")) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
                LinearLayout controls = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_video_gallery, null);
                viewHolder.addView(controls);
                info_one_video_gallery = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info_one_video_gallery);
                monument_name_one_video_gallery = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.monument_name_one_video_gallery);
                one_video_gallary_imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.one_video_gallary_imageview);
                one_video_gallary_thumbnail = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.one_video_gallary_thumbnail);
                final ImageView cancel_video_image_view= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cancel_video_image_view);
                cancel_video_image_view.setClickable(true);


                one_video_gallary_imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(),MediaFullScreenImageActivity.class);
                        String monument_images = PropertyFile.TargetOne + "_images";
                        intent.putExtra("monument_images",monument_images);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                one_video_gallary_thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaVideoActivity.class);
                        String monument = PropertyFile.TargetOne;
                        intent.putExtra("monument", monument);
                        String monument_images = PropertyFile.TargetOne + "_images";
                        intent.putExtra("monument_images", monument_images);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });


                if(cancel_video_image_view.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    cancel_video_image_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cancel_video_image_view.setClickable(true);
                    one_video_gallary_imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    one_video_gallary_thumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    info_one_video_gallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    monument_name_one_video_gallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                cancel_video_image_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked the button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        one_video_gallary_imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        one_video_gallary_thumbnail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        cancel_video_image_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        info_one_video_gallery.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        monument_name_one_video_gallery.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                    }
                });

     }
```

Comment: Along with downvoting, people should at least explain what they felt wrong with the post (spam/no-code/format/code request/etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think that you should not put onClickListener in the runOnUiThread. Because when onTargetRecongnized was called, it will just check if statements in short time and just finish the runnable.

Comment: hi @luopleming , i am using wikitude AugmentedReality sdk with android app. we must  write inside runOnUiThread according to wikitude sdk.

Comment: What about you take all those onClickListeners out of the runOnUiThread then when on of those are clicked you run runOnUiThread.

Comment: wikitude sdk will not work properly if i do like that.

Comment: Hmm.. eithery way this wouldn't work, so I suggest you put that code out of runOnUiThread. But it's your choice, as there maybe other ways to fix it.